# Pasting HTML into IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, paste, richtext

One of our products uses a Javascript Rich text editor, which has the ability to accept pasted HTML/Word and clean it up so the html is XHtml valid and presentable.

This has been working fine for a few years, but recently we've been having complaints about pasting; from users with IE8.

It turns out that regardless of setting the group policy setting for allowing pasting, or prompt for pasting; if IE8 mode is enabled, it won't paste.

If you turn on compatibility mode, it works correctly, but we'd like to have a solution that works across the board.

Has anyone had this issue or similar ?

Unfortunately, we deal with a lot of corporate/local goverment entities that don't have the flexibility to change their browser/policies without submission through strict change-request red-tape :(

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't worried about formatted text then try the clipBoardData object. It's not ideal but its about the only thing that works other than running in compatibility mode via the web developer tools.

Comment: It's not nice, but yup - seems to be the only thing that works.

Oh well; going to have to implement a flash content editor or something.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but could you use the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` meta-tag to force compatibility-mode for IE8 users?

I think some intranet group policy settings may override that and it's a sticking plaster rather than a solution, but it may get you by while you find a proper fix.

Comment: A colleague has tried this and sadly, it doesn't seem to work. Slightly odd as turning on compatability mode in the browser is just fine ...